# Flex Direction Column not working on mobile phones?

Tags: html, css, ios, flexbox

I ran into a problem recently with flexbox. I had a flex container with numerous flex items inside, set to wrap. The items were also flex containers, given a basis of a third of the parent at larger screen sizes sized up to half on tablets and 100% on mobile displays. You can probably picture the columns collapsing in your head. It was working great until I checked my phone and saw that the items weren't displaying at all on mobile.

I looked around and saw that sometimes flex-wrap acts weird in iOS, so I set flex wrap to none and flex direction column on mobile, but it still didn't make the images show. My solution ended up being switching the flex items to display: block on mobile, since I didn't really need the flex functionality anymore. This caused the items to appear again.

Anyone else encounter this? If so do you know why it happened and what your solution was? There's a code sample below for my finished code (it's in Sass). Worth noting that this is a flex container within a flex container.

```css
.listing {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: calc(33.3% - 1.5rem);
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    margin-right: .75rem;
    margin-left: .75rem;

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-right: .75rem !important;
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
        display: block;
        flex-basis: calc(100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post enough code to reproduce the problem, so we can actually see what you're talking about.

Comment: Considering your media query overlaps and most likely is in the wrong order, any unexpected behavior should be expected